# Change the default width in my css document

Tags: css, html, width

I want to change/override my default width in my css document, so that I can implement an HTML5 animation on my site.

I have inserted this on the site:

```
<div id="nakuru_hype_container" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:100%;height:3300px;overflow:hidden;" aria-live="polite">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://www.weinhonig.com/wp-content/hype/nakuru.hyperesources/nakuru_hype_generated_script.js?44126"></script>
</div>
```

And have added this line of code to my css:

```
#nakuru_hype_container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The animation by itself is in full screen and in testing also is shown in full screen in a browser, so therefore something must be wrong with my css.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important` property to override style:

```
#nakuru_hype_container {
width: 100% !important;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

But remember, the style of the container depends on the parent container.